# How to get product details in the catalogue module?

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

How to get product details in the catalogue module?

I have a code in the overriden `mod_virtuemart_category`:

```
$productModel = VmModel::getModel('Product');
$products = $productModel->getProductListing(false, false, true, true, true, true, $category->virtuemart_category_id, false, 0);
............
<?php foreach($products as $product) { ?>
    <?php
        if (!empty($product->images[0])) {
                            $image = $product->images[0]->displayMediaThumb ('class="featuredProductImage"', FALSE);
        } else {
            $image = '';
        }
        echo JHTML::_ ('link', JRoute::_ ('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id=' . $product->virtuemart_product_id . '&virtuemart_category_id=' . $product->virtuemart_category_id), $image, array('title' => $product->product_name));
    ?>
<?php } ?>
```

But the image is not shown. The same situation is with the price:

```
<?php if ($show_price) {
    if (!empty($product->prices['salesPrice'])) {
        echo $currency->createPriceDiv ('salesPrice', '', $product->prices, FALSE, FALSE, 1.0, TRUE);
    }
    if (!empty($product->prices['salesPriceWithDiscount'])) {
        echo $currency->createPriceDiv ('salesPriceWithDiscount', '', $product->prices, FALSE, FALSE, 1.0, TRUE);
    }
}
?>
```

The same time code `<?php echo $product->product_name ?>` outputs product's name. Prices and images are assigned for the product. In the overriden module `mod_virtuemart_product` this code works just fine.

UPD The `print_r($product)` shows that there are no fields `images[]` and `prices[]` in overridden `mod_virtuemart_category`. But in the overridden `mod_virtuemart_product` those fields exist.